# Initialize array of arrays for construction on the fly

Tags: arrays, julia

How do you declare an array that contain arrays in julia?

I have `a=Int32[]` which creates an empty array of Int32 (of course), but I would like later to construct on the fly something like

```
if ...
    push!(a, [r,s]) # (*)
...
```

where `r` and `s` are integers. I tried `a=Int32[Int32[]]` but it does not work when doing (*). I don't have the specific shape of `a`, so I need to declare it without this restriction.

Answer (score 9):

`Int32[]` creates a `Vector{Int32}` which is a `Vector` with element type `Int32`. You want a `Vector` with element type `Vector{Int32}`, so you can use `Vector{Vector{Int32}}()` or `Vector{Int32}[]`. Note that `Vector{T}` is an alias for `Array{T,1}`, aka an `Array` with element type `T` and 1 dimension, so when Julia prints out the type, it won't use the word `Vector`.

```
julia> v=Vector{Vector{Int32}}()
0-element Array{Array{Int32,1},1}

julia> push!(v,[1,2,3])
1-element Array{Array{Int32,1},1}:
 Int32[1, 2, 3]
```

or

```
julia> x=Vector{Int32}[]
0-element Array{Array{Int32,1},1}

julia> push!(x,[4,5,6])
1-element Array{Array{Int32,1},1}:
 Int32[4, 5, 6]
```